# How to get the 2's complement value of a BigInteger of arbitrary length

Tags: java, android, biginteger, twos-complement, negative-number

Is there a method in BigInteger to get the 2's complement value? 
For eg: if there is a BigInteger with a negative value

```
BigInteger a = new BigInteger("-173B8EC504479C3E95DEB0460411962F9EF2ECE0D3AACD749BE39E1006FC87B8", 16);
```

then I want to get the 2's complement in a BigInteger form

```
BigInteger b = E8C4713AFBB863C16A214FB9FBEE69D0610D131F2C55328B641D61EFF9037848
```

I can subtract the first BigInteger from 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF to get the second BigInteger but is there a generic method to calculate this for a BigInteger of any length?

Comment: Sorry I don't have the answer but what exactly are you using this for?

Comment: We are following a protocol on both Android & iOS. In iOS the BIGNUM is resulting a +ve number but in Android the BigInteger is showing a -ve number (2's complement). We need to match both the values for our calculations.

Comment: And why you are using BigInteger for that? I assume this is more a problem of the protocol parser. I recommend that you edit your question and add information and code on what data you receive and how you parse it and what you do afterwards with it.

Comment: Err, `BigInteger.negate()`? Is this such a mystery?

Comment: BigInteger.negate() is simply changing the sign but the value is not changed.

Comment: @EJP: That would simply output `"173....7B8"`, not `"E8C...848"`. Not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To *make* this value its two's complement, you will have to manipulate the contents. That is of course impossible, so you first get the contents out, manipulate them and then get them into a new `BigInteger`:

```
public static BigInteger twosComplement(BigInteger original)
{
    // for negative BigInteger, top byte is negative  
    byte[] contents = original.toByteArray();

    // prepend byte of opposite sign
    byte[] result = new byte[contents.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(contents, 0, result, 1, contents.length);
    result[0] = (contents[0] < 0) ? 0 : (byte)-1;

    // this will be two's complement
    return new BigInteger(result);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    BigInteger a = new BigInteger("-173B8EC504479C3E95DEB0460411962F9EF2ECE0D3AACD749BE39E1006FC87B8", 16);
    BigInteger b = twosComplement(a);

    System.out.println(a.toString(16).toUpperCase());
    System.out.println(b.toString(16).toUpperCase());

    // for comparison, from question:
    System.out.println("E8C4713AFBB863C16A214FB9FBEE69D0610D131F2C55328B641D61EFF9037848");
}
```

Output:

```
-173B8EC504479C3E95DEB0460411962F9EF2ECE0D3AACD749BE39E1006FC87B8
E8C4713AFBB863C16A214FB9FBEE69D0610D131F2C55328B641C61EFF9037848
E8C4713AFBB863C16A214FB9FBEE69D0610D131F2C55328B641D61EFF9037848
```

And this new `BigInteger` is really the two's complement, not just a re-interpretation of the bits.

Comment: If you don't want to modify positive BigIntegers, then either don't call `twosComplement()` if the BigInteger is positive already, or let it return when `original` is positive. The above will convert -ve into +ve and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you Rudy, I have included the below condition for -ve BigIntegers and it is working fine.          if (b.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) <0) {
            b = twosComplement(b);
        }