# How to get an unsigned byte array from a BigInteger in Java?

Tags: java, biginteger, unsigned-integer, unsigned-char

I need to convert a [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) to an unsigned integer encoded in big-endian format but I am having issues since [BigInteger.toByteArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray()) returns a signed representation. How can I convert this value to an unsigned format?

**(Relatively) Helpful Background**

I am working on some code that uses JNI to have c++ call some Java methods to handle some cryptographic functionality (this is a Microsoft CNG provider that offloads some functionality to Java). I have the public key in Java and the BigInteger values that I need to convert are the [coordinates of the Elliptic Curve Public Key](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/spec/ECPoint.html#getAffineX()). According to the [CNG documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#code-snippet-2) I need to provide these points as "unsigned integers encoded in big-endian format".

**Edit**

In hindsight, this might have been a silly post. I was getting confused with negative and positive numbers and how to handle that (and because it's late and my mind has turned to mush) but it turns out that I don't need to deal with that since the [elliptic curve points won't be negative](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16604/why-are-there-only-positive-value-points-on-an-elliptic-curve). Thank you to everyone who responded on here! I will leave this up in case it helps anyone else.

Comment: If integer in question is positive, what is the difference? If it is negative, then what should be the result of conversion to unsigned?

Comment: Take a look at [the answer I gave to a similar qustion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918190/how-to-get-the-2s-complement-value-of-a-biginteger-of-arbitrary-length/38931124#38931124).

Comment: In other words, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/38918190/95954

Comment: Short answer:prepend a 0 byte to the byte array and load it back into a BigInteger. Then it is positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of a 2's complement reference value we can do this like below

```
private static final BigInteger TWO_COMPL_REF = BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(64);

    public static byte[] parseBigIntegerPositive(BigInteger b) {
        if (b.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0)
            b = b.add(TWO_COMPL_REF);

       byte[] unsignedbyteArray= b.toByteArray();
        return unsignedbyteArray;
    }
```

Comment: That does not return the same value, does it?

Comment: @rudy I think yes beacause it will just give unsigned version of byte array

Comment: By adding 1^64 to a negative BigInteger? Yes, well, if you truncate it to an unsiged integer, then perhaps. Otherwise, certainly not.